# Codeblocks16.01 in Ubuntu 16.04 stops working after opening the source file!

Tags: 16.04, ide, code-blocks

After I start codeblocks and opening my project and then opening source code from the management panel, everything suddenly stops working!        (Codeblocks hangs) and after some seconds, the application turns into gray collar (like when Firefox has a problem with flash player and it hangs!)

It should also be noted that I installed the ppa.
Also removing and reinstalling did not solve the problem.

thanks for any suggestion in advance.

[image: codeblocks-pic]

Comment: Did you build it yourself? If yes did you link it against libwxgtk2.8?

Comment: I downloaded the package from:
https://launchpad.net/~damien-moore/+archive/ubuntu/codeblocks-stable
the package itself works fine, since I installed it on another computer with ubuntu 15.10

Comment: mhmm damien makes normally pretty stable packages, but there can be so much wrong I am at a loss, i had build mine myself on the 16.04

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I found the solution, by disabling the the symbols browser problem is solved.

**"Settings -> Editor -> Code completion -> Symbols browser -> Disable symbols browser"**

But anyway it seems to be a problem since same version of code::blocks in Ubuntu 15 works fine.